# i have my code but i cant show this in my page

Tags: phtml

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('web/web')->getCollection()->setOrder('web_id', 'ASC');
//$a = array();
foreach ($collection as $value) {
    $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($value['created_time']));
    $a[$date][] = $value['filename'];
    //$d[] = $date;

}
//echo $a[0];
echo "<pre>";
//print_r($d);
print_r($a);
echo "<pre/>";
```

Comment: arrey show like Array ( [2015-01-23] => Array ( [0] => Chrysanthemum.jpg [1] => [2] => ) [2015-01-22] => Array ( [0] => Desert.jpg ) ) - See more at: http://localhost/tdmagento/index.php/web#sthash.yB0zjqAD.dpuf

Comment: put more details other wise question goes to close

Answer (score 1):

if you want to access the data from collection using array then you need to replace following line.

Replace:

```
foreach ($collection as $value) {
```

With:

```
foreach ($collection->getData() as $value) {
```